# How do you make a distinct query on GORM subdocument fields?

Tags: hibernate, grails, gorm-mongodb

Given Grails 2.3.8 and Mongo 2.6.0, and this (simplified) domain class:

```
db.account.findOne()
{
    "name":"Test Account",
    "customer": {
        "state": "CA"
    }
}
```

where every account has a customer subdocument with a "state" string.  To get a list of all states across all customers, I would think to do something like this:

```
def states = Account.createCriteria().list {
    projections{
        distinct("customer.state")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work because of an existing bug - https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-397

Is there a workaround?

I can do this:
`Account.collection.distinct("customer.state")`
but is there a more Grails-ish way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY" for DISTINCT record.

```
def users = Account..withCriteria {
        resultTransformer Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
}
```